# Swift Get Keys and Values from NSCache

Tags: swift, nscache

I have an NS Cache, and I would like to get ALL of the objects that it stores as an array. The keys will be needed as well. Everything I have read says that I should be able to basically treat it like a dictionary, but I get compiler errors when I try:

`var tinyCache: NSCache<NSString, NSString> = NSCache<NSString, NSString>()
 let keys = tinyCache.keys
 let values = tinyCache.values`

The compiler error tells me that NS Cache doesn't have a member 'keys' or 'values' I have looked through the documentation here and can't find any indication of how to get the keys or values:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscache

So how do I get all of the keys and values from the cache?

I have looked at all of the other SO questions and haven't found a suitable solution for Swift

Comment: I don't think that NSCache offers such a method. Why do you need it?

Comment: I am caching the results of API calls to a Rails Server. When a user makes a GET call to an Index endpoint, multiple items are returned. I want the cache to be able to give back a specific item in addition to ALL of the items pulled down by the Index call.

Comment: @MartinR, it would really help with debugging multithreaded projects.